# Need help searching an array... very hard for me

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Got a small problem. I don't know how to search one array so I can pull that same array number from the other 2 arrays. I know how to test for a lot of stuff so that won't be a problem.

The end result on this project is the user will place the amount they are willing to pay for a make of the car and the page will display the data. HOWEVER I don't know how to search the `carArray()` to find the index number and use that index number to find the other stuff. I did find something that did this (somewhat) earlier but I don't know how to modify it for me to keep that index number as a int and use it to search and display the other arrays.

I will need this in future projects later.

```
Public Class paymentPage

    Private Sub car_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles car.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub price_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles price.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim carArray() As String = {"Ford", "Chevy", "Mazda"}
        Dim sellAmount() As Decimal = {32700, 35625, 24780}
        Dim leaseAmount() As Decimal = {425, 505, 385}

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using three arrays instead of using a class to represent each car and its related values, and then keeping a `List` or `Dictionary` of those classes? Is this your homework? If it is, you need to at least make some effort to solve this yourself. You've provided the array declarations, but no attempt to actually do anything with them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim cars as new List(Of Car)({car1,car2,car3})

Dim indexOfCar2 = Array.IndexOf(cars.ToArray(),car2)
```

Since its dirt simple to convert to an array then you can use the built in function. Keep in mind that you need to override GetHash and Equals to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make this a class object? Easier to reuse later.

```
Public Class Car
  Public Property Make As String
  Public Property Value As Double
  Public Property Lease As Double
End Class
```

Then make a collection of them:

```
Private cars As New List(Of Car)
cars.Add(New Car With {.Make = "Ford", .Value = 32700, .Lease = 425})
cars.Add(New Car With {.Make = "Chevy", .Value = 35625, .Lease = 505})
cars.Add(New Car With {.Make = "Mazda", .Value = 24780, .Lease = 385})
```

For your requirements:

```
Private Function getIndexByName(make As string) As Integer
 Dim result As Integer = -1
 For i As Integer = 0 To carArray.Length -1
  If carArray(i) = make Then
   result = i
   Exit for
  End If
 Next
 Return Result
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim mazdalease = leaseAmt(getIndexByName("Mazda"))
```

Comment: That would work but my teacher doesn't want to use that yet. Otherwise i would. But that would make things easier later. but how would you search through this to find what you need.

Comment: I get they need to teach you arrays, but this is not appropriate at all. This is how anyone with OOP design would implement this request. Schools need to step up to the plate and quite doing this ridiculous methodology.

Comment: Tell me about it man i got a prick of a teacher. I mean a real ******* prick.

Comment: but how would you search an array to find the index number. once i find the index number i can do all the if else statements.

Comment: very.Thanks for the info. I will have to use this and more. This may help fix a few problems i have been having. I am also going to start studying vb code from you guys, cus my school isn't following what is needed.